# Add element in option

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating this post because I'm trying to add and remove option in an HTML select from a function.

I've searched everywhere but unfortunately I didn't find anything.

thank you in advance for your help!

```js
methods: {
  addElement() {
    // function add option in actions select
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <select name="actions" v-model="model.actions" class="form-control">
          </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: please provide what you have tried so far

Comment: show your options and functions that you're saying

Comment: Right now I've got nothing, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: then we can't help you!

Comment: options.splice(0,1)? when using vue data driven

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: For delete one option from options you shoud do like this: options.splice(index,1);

Comment: For add one option to options you shoud do like this: options.push({ /* your option */});

Comment: Thank @Sherzodbek and Estradiaz, i will try that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from the vue docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select (find using `v-for` with `select` at that page):

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>


new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
})
```

If you want to add option to `select` just create some method `addOption(option)`:

```
methods:{
    addOption(option){
        this.options.push(option);
    }
}
```